# AWS: [Iam] the very model of a modern major synonym request

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

- [iam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iam) - 242 questions, wiki
- [amazon-iam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-iam) - 191 questions, identical wiki excerpt
- [aws-iam-roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-iam-roles) - 12 questions, no wiki

Even though [amazon-iam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-iam) is slightly smaller question wise, I think that it should be the master as it's more descriptive.

I think that [aws-iam-roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-iam-roles) serves no purpose and all questions should be merged into [amazon-iam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-iam), without preserving the synonym.

<sub>[Gilbert and Sullivan: I am the very model of a modern major general](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zSGWoXDFM64)</sub>
[image: screenshot]

Comment: I do not like them, Sam [tag:iam], I do not like [tag:amazon-iam]. (Although it contradicts the proposal...)

Answer (score 1):

[iam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iam) should be removed as a synonym for [amazon-iam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-iam) as [Identity and Access Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_management) is a term that defines a set of industry standards and protocols. A general question could be asked that has no relation to the amazon products.

[A new request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418620/help-iam-trapped-in-the-amazon-and-cant-get-out?noredirect=1#comment914501_418620) was made and resolved.

Comment: This should get posted as a new request, so a status tag can get added to it.