# Help, [iam] trapped in the Amazon and can't get out

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-removal-request

The [iam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iam) should not remain a synonym of [amazon-iam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-iam) when [IAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_management) is an industry abbreviation.

Comment: What's wrong with [tag:identity-management]

Comment: that seems like the right place for the iam synonym

Comment: Seems reasonable to me. I'll change the synonym to point to the general term instead of Amazon's specific implementation

Comment: Likely, the questions having the [[tag:iam]] tag were all about Amazon's variant of it, so merging was the easiest course of action to correct that. The synonym can be broken/removed now; that's easy to do. (Zoe jumped in and did it while I was called away to deal with another matter.) What I would recommend that you (or someone else) do is to check the questions having the [[tag:amazon-iam]] tag and confirm that all of them are actually about the Amazon implementation. If not, they should be retagged.

Comment: Odd. I figured this question would be about [dog-fooding](https://www.iams.com/).

Comment: [Wikipedia disambiguation page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IAM)

Comment: @CodyGray Well, only 4.7k questions to check through...